# Mostrar y ocultar texto en un Button Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, botón

Estoy intentando colocar un botón con tkinter que de inicio no aparezca su texto puesto sobre el hasta que se de click sobre el. Estoy intentando hacerlo de la siguiente manera pero no me funciona los botones salen igual en blanco.
tengo dudas en los argumentos de función dentro del botón pero no estoy seguro que me falta hacer

```
def callback_btn(btn,text):
        btn.configure(text=text)

def dibujando_tab(matriz, numero_filas, numero_columnas, frame):
    for row_index in range(numero_filas):
        Grid.rowconfigure(frame, row_index, weight=2)
        for col_index in range(numero_columnas):
            Grid.columnconfigure(frame, col_index, weight=2)
            texto=str(matriz[row_index][col_index][(row_index, col_index)][::]).replace("[","")
            for char in n:
                texto = texto.replace(char,"")
            btn = Button(frame)
            btn.configure( command = lambda: callback_btn(btn, texto)) 
            btn.grid(row=row_index, column=col_index, sticky=N+S+E+W)
```

Answer (score 0):

Como no sé con qué datos se hace la llamada a **dibujando_tab**, simplifiqué el problema y lo dejé del siguiente modo:

```
from tkinter import Tk, Button

def callback_btn(btn,text):
  btn.configure(text=text)

    v = Tk()
    v.title("V")
    v.geometry("200x100+100+100")

    texto = "HICISTE CLIC"
    boton = Button(v, text="", command=lambda: callback_btn(boton, texto))
    boton.place(x=50, y=30, width=100, height=30)
```

Realicé la invocación a la función **callback_btn**, y el resultado es el esperado.

Recuerdo que en algún momento tuve un problema similar, en el que no se refrescaban algunos cambios de aspecto sobre los controles, para eso, tuve que usar la función **update()**. Aunque para el caso del ejemplo que hice no es necesario, bastaría con usar **v.update()** luego de modificar el botón.

Comment: recuerda que no es solo poner texto, lo que se considera de baja calidad; sino además explicarlo

Comment: Gracias, lo editaré.